# Custom model manager gets clobbered by prefetch_related

Tags: python, django

I have a model and a corresponding model manager:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        return super().select_related('group').get(**kwargs)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', ...)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', ...)
    # ... others ...

    objects = MyModelManager()
```

The model manager does a `select_related()` in the `get()` routine so that I always have the given foreign key field joined (I'll likely be referring to it often). When I call the `get()` routine, things work just as I expect:

```
obj = models.MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
print(obj.group)  # Doesn't hit the database a second time
```

However, if I make a call to something like `prefetch_related()`, my custom manager gets discarded along the way:

```
obj = models.MyModel.objects.prefetch_related('tags').get(pk=1)
print(obj.group)  # Hits the database a second time to get the group
```

The reason becomes pretty clear when I print the types:

```
x = models.MyModel.objects
print(type(x))  # Yields <class 'base.models.TestCaseManager'>
y = models.MyModel.objects.prefetch_related('tags')
print(type(y))  # Yields <class 'django.db.models.QuerySet'>
```

#### My Question

Can I get chained calls to return my custom manager instance, rather than the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API definitions for model mangers explicitly return `QuerySet` objects, not the manager object. The returned `QuerySet` still has all the customizations from the manager, assuming the manager is implemented correctly. There's nothing special about `prefetch_related` here, the same happens with `filter`, `all`, `none`, `annotate`, etc. Basically a manager object is a generator of `QuerySet` objects, and many `QuerySet` methods are also generators of `QuerySet` objects. You should not expect to be able to call manager-specific methods like `get_or_create` after calling a method that generates a `QuerySet`.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not interested in calling a second manager-specific method, but I do want the `select_related()` call I'm using in `get_queryset()` to stick around. I'm not real sure why it's not...

Comment: It is sticking around. Try doing `print(y.query)`.

Comment: So the `select_related()` actually happens in the manager's `get()` call (overriding the default). I see now that this gets back to your initial point that I shouldn't expect to call a manager-specific method (in this case my custom `get()` function) after getting a queryset. Is there a better place for something like this to live?

Comment: That's basically the canonical use-case for custom managers, defining a `get_queryset()` override that adds specific filtering, annotating, etc. The official documentation for model managers covers a lot: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/